# Correcting wrong photo in old granted UK tourist visa

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, immigration, uk-visa

I'm applying for a new visa to the UK. Previously, I've had two visas to the UK granted, and have never had a visa application rejected.

**8.5 Years Ago...**

My first visa, issued roughly 8.5 years ago, was a tourist visa. At the time, I was a child travelling on a school trip to the UK and accompanied by teachers, and so my visa application was handled by the teachers organizing the trip.

Somewhere along the application process, someone made a mistake and instead of having a photo of myself on the issued visa, a photo of my sibling was used instead. Since we were high-school students (under-18 teenagers), our teachers only granted us our passports at the airport just before boarding the airplane, to show the ushers right outside the aircraft.

I managed to get past immigration both into the UK and on the return trip back home. When I returned home, I told my parents of the mistake; my parents subsequently informed the trip-organizing teachers of the mistake and later on, assured me that the issue had been resolved.

**4 Years Ago...**

Four years ago, I applied for a student visa to study in the UK, which was granted successfully. I sent off my passport to the UK immigration office in my country and within a few weeks, my student visa came back with no hiccups.

I've travelled in and out of the UK a couple times over the past 4 years and have never had any trouble at immigration.

**Present Day**

I'm applying for a work-visa (i.e. Tier 2 visa) in the UK and have already received a high-paying job offer from a top tech company here (think Facebook/Google/Apple/Amazon).

As part of my application, I need to submit photos/scans of all my old visas to the UK. To avoid any hiccups during the process, I also hoped to submit documentation from the UKVI (UK Visas and Immigration Office) acknowledging the mistake that was made in my old tourist visa. This way, the case officer processing my work-visa application will not reject my application due to the old mistake.

However, it appears that neither my parents nor my old school has any documentation relating to that photo error that occurred nearly 8.5 years ago. I'm able to get an official letter from my old school explaining that they are largely responsible for the mistake (since they handled my application and I was a minor), as well as an official letter from the British High Commission in my home country acknowledging the mistake.

**Question**

Given this, is it likely that the application for my Tier-2 work visa (once submitted) will still be rejected even after including these additional endorsements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think your application will be rejected.

Reasons:

- you, as a minor, were not responsible for the situation
- the organizers confirmed that they made the mistake
- they informed the British High Commission of the situation
- you gave a complete, accurate, documented travel history

The last point is the most important part since you, now as an adult, are acting in a responsible mannor.